# Error on bounty assignment

Tags: support, bounty

My fault, when assigning bounty to his question:

[Lagrangian mechanics, infinitesimal movements expressed in coordinate basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558268/)

I've pushed on an answer not the expected one (yes, even after the warning about impossible of undo).

Can moderators undo the action?

Can I at least open a second bounty to reward the other answer?

Comment: I am the one who received the unintended bounty. And I clearly agree that the other answer is more deserving of the bounty, that's why I have started a bounty of 100 on your question, and I'll be awarding it to the other answer after 24 hours.

Comment: @FakeMod: thanks a lot

Comment: Update: The bounty has been successfully given to the other answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [bounty help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> - **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**
> - [...]
> - Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

There's a minor exception to the bolded statement. Since bountied questions can't be closed by ordinary users, sometimes we will refund a bounty in order to close a question. But we don't have the tools to refund a bounty that's been awarded already. I can imagine a lot of mischief and bad feelings that could come from such a power, even if its users intended well.

You certainly can offer an additional bounty on the same question. If it's not available immediately after awarding your first one, try waiting a couple of days; the logic is probably like the logic which prevents a new question from being bountied immediately.

Comment: "under any circumstances": not my favorite phrase.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that we tend to refund a bounty when we suspect that the bounty was offered in bad faith (e.g. to prevent people from voting to close the question), or when there seems to be a particularly strong case that the question needs to be closed, enough to overcome the fact that it sat around for two days without getting closed already. Refunding a bounty is very much not a typical thing for the moderators to do.

Comment: Right. I would guess that we refund a bounty about once a year.